# Error generating a model reading corpus from a big .txt file

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, tagged-corpus

i'm trying to read the file corpus.txt (training set) and generate a model, the output must be called lexic.txt and contain the word, the tag and the number of ocurrences...for small training sets it works, but for the university given training set (30mb .txt file, millions of lines) the code does not work,I imagine it will be a problem with the efficiency and therefore the system runs out of memory...can anybody help me with the code please?

Here I attach my code:

```
from collections import Counter

file=open('corpus.txt','r')
data=file.readlines()
file.close()

palabras = []
count_list = []

for linea in data:
   linea.decode('latin_1').encode('UTF-8') # para los acentos
   palabra_tag = linea.split('\n')
   palabras.append(palabra_tag[0])

cuenta = Counter(palabras) # dictionary for count ocurrences for a word + tag 

#Assign for every word + tag the number of times appears
for palabraTag in palabras:
    for i in range(len(palabras)):
        if palabras[i] == palabraTag:       
            count_list.append([palabras[i], str(cuenta[palabraTag])])


#We delete repeated ones
finalList = []
for i in count_list:
    if i not in finalList:
        finalList.append(i)


outfile = open('lexic.txt', 'w') 
outfile.write('Palabra\tTag\tApariciones\n')

for i in range(len(finalList)):
    outfile.write(finalList[i][0]+'\t'+finalList[i][1]+'\n') # finalList[i][0] is the word + tag and finalList[i][1] is the numbr of ocurrences

outfile.close()
```

And here you can see a sample of the corpus.txt:

```
Al  Prep
menos   Adv
cinco   Det
reclusos    Adj
murieron    V
en  Prep
las Det
últimas Adj
24  Num
horas   NC
en  Prep
las Det
cárceles    NC
de  Prep
Valencia    NP
y   Conj
Barcelona   NP
en  Prep
incidentes  NC
en  Prep
los Det
que Pron
su  Det
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What doesn't work? Is the output wrong? Does it not run to completion?

Comment: @David It works perfectly for small .txt files, but for a big .txt file, the task does not end and abortion is prompt in the terminal

Comment: What does the message say? Have you tried watching your memory when it runs?

Comment: @David That memory is insufficient :(

Comment: How much memory are you working with?

Comment: @David How could I know? I tried in different computers and same problem...I think the problem is related to the lists and the size limits, may be we can do the same operations more efficiently with other data structures but I don't know how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I improved the code using dictionary, here is the result working 100% fine:

```
file=open('corpus.txt','r')
data=file.readlines()
file.close()

diccionario = {}

for linea in data:
    linea.decode('latin_1').encode('UTF-8') # para los acentos
    palabra_tag = linea.split('\n')
    cadena = str(palabra_tag[0])
    if(diccionario.has_key(cadena)):
        aux = diccionario.get(cadena)
        aux += 1
        diccionario.update({cadena:aux})
    else:
        diccionario.update({cadena:1})

outfile = open('lexic.txt', 'w')
outfile.write('Palabra\tTag\tApariciones\n')

for key, value in diccionario.iteritems() :
    s = str(value)
    outfile.write(key +" "+s+'\n')
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to reduce your memory usage if you combine these two chunks of code.

```
#Assign for every word + tag the number of times appears
for palabraTag in palabras:
    for i in range(len(palabras)):
        if palabras[i] == palabraTag:       
            count_list.append([palabras[i], str(cuenta[palabraTag])])


#We delete repeated ones
finalList = []
for i in count_list:
    if i not in finalList:
        finalList.append(i)
```

You can check to see if an item exists in the count list already and by doing so, not add duplicates in the first place. This should reduce your memory usage. See below;

```
#Assign for every word + tag the number of times appears
for palabraTag in palabras:
    for i in range(len(palabras)):
        if palabras[i] == palabraTag and
           [palabras[i], str(cuenta[palabraTag])] not in count_list:
                count_list.append([palabras[i], str(cuenta[palabraTag])])
```